# Spring & MyBatis - how to get MyBatis databseId in a @Bean annotated function

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to create a Spring bean based on a MyBatis `databaseId` like so:

```
@Bean
fun getSomeBean(@Autowired databaseId: String): SomeBean {
  if(databaseId.equals("mysql")){
    return SomeMySqlBean()
  } else {
    return SomeNonMysqlBean()
  }

}
```

How do I get the `databaseId` to be injected with MyBatis?

Comment: `databaseId` is not a Spring bean. You may be able to get it via `SqlSessionFactory` which exists as a Spring bean. `sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().getDatabaseId()`. Please see the mybatis-spring [documentation](https://mybatis.org/spring/factorybean.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at some of the API documentation and came up with this - works nicely and now I can construct a couple of the vendor-specific objects I need:

```
@Bean
fun databaseId(sqlSessionFactory: SqlSessionFactory): String {
    return sqlSessionFactory.configuration.databaseId
}
```